# setOnMouseClicked event doesn't call my switch case

Tags: java, javafx, switch-statement, case

I'm working on a JavaFX game, which is Snake. I have split up my huge class into two separate ones - the game worked before this separation - and now I can't make my setOnMouseClicked event from Class 2 to call the switch case in Class 1. I'm using an Enum class called Direction as my cases. This is how my MouseClicked event looks like in Class 2.

```
SnakeGame snakeGame = new SnakeGame();
MenuButton btnRestart = new MenuButton("RESTART");
btnRestart.setOnMouseClicked(event-> {

            FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5), this);
            ft.setFromValue(1);
            ft.setToValue(0);
            ft.setOnFinished(evt-> setVisible(false));
            snakeGame.restartFromMenu();
            ft.play();

        } );
```

What I want it to do; is to click on a button, and then restart the game. I'm calling the method from Class 1 (snakeGame), called restartFromMenu. Which looks like this:

```
 public void restartFromMenu(){

    setDirection(Direction.CONTINUE);               
    getTimeline().play();
    System.out.println(getDirection());
    running = true;
}
```

This is how the switch case looks:

```
    KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.2), event->{
        if(!running){
            return;}

         switch (getDirection()){

         case CONTINUE:
            System.out.println("Inside Case Continue");
            tail.setTranslateX(snake.lastIndexOf(tailX) + BLOCK_SIZE);
            tail.setTranslateY(snake.lastIndexOf(tailY));
            getTimeline().playFromStart();
            break;
            });
```

I managed to use another switch case with getCode() in Class 1, and call my method from there if I press 'P', and then it works. Like this:

```
 scene.setOnKeyPressed(event ->{
        if(!moved){
            return;}
    switch(event.getCode()){
        case P:
                restartFromMenu();
                break;
                }
            moved = false;
                });
```

What happens is that I click on my menu button called 'Restart', the menu fades away, and the game is frozen, until I press 'P'. Since it works with calling my method, I don't think my method restartFromMenu is wrong. How do I make it so I can call on my switch case properly from Class 2?

Comment: It's hard to tell with the code you posted. Could it be that btwRestart.setOnmouseClicked should be snakeGame.btnRestart.setOnmouseClicked?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have updated my code so you can see that btnRestart is initialized in Class 2. Sorry for that.

Comment: Not enough code to be able to tell, but it seems strange that you are instantiating SnakeGame in the second class. Don't you already have an instance created at that point?

Comment: Yes I do. Should I instead do this: SnakeGame snakeGame? Instead of creating a new instance of it? Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You need a reference to the existing instance.